# How to store user generated content in Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb

I want to create an website where users can create their own teaching resources, e.g. blocks of text with embedded images etc.

How should I store this in a database in rails? I've heard mongoDB is good for storing documents but I was planning on using postgresql for the user database etc. and have read that generally you shouldn't mix different types of db

I'm sure this is an obvious question but I couldn't find an answer anywhere...

Thanks,

Graham

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things you could do.

**`1.`** Use **PostgreSQL** for both the Users table and the TeachingResources table. You could simply use a `content` column of type `text` to save all the data.

---

**`2.`** Use **PostgreSQL** but use the `HStore` functionality to basically [store a hash of objects](http://schneems.com/post/19298469372/you-got-nosql-in-my-postgres-using-hstore-in-rails) of your choosing, this gives you more flexibility. Rails 4 will [support this by default](http://travisjeffery.com/b/2012/02/using-postgress-hstore-with-rails/), but there is also a [gem](https://github.com/softa/activerecord-postgres-hstore) you can use.

---

**`3.`** Use a **combination of PostgreSQL and MongoDB** (or any other NoSQL solution) in your app. I don't see this as a bad solution, but it does put you outside of the "new user constraints" in Rails, so this might not be the best route to start with

---

**`4.`** Go **NoSQL all the way**. There is no reason you shouldn't be able to use MongoDB for your User model. However, you are right that this type of datastorage can not give full [ACID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) guarantees, so be careful with product planning and know it's vulnerabilities (but also its strengths).

Comment: Thanks for a comprehensive answer, very useful overview which I can now use as a starting point to learn more.